# how to call a thread using java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to call up a thread to execute some code then die after finishing,
what is the best way to do this in java?

so for example.

```
public void update_labels() throws Exception{

...
call the thread from here, obviously non blocking

...
}
```

the thread will connect to a database and fetch/return some variables and then terminate

Comment: Did you explore Java documentations? You just need to create a runnable instance and pass it to a thread and start it. Once a thread finishes all the statements within runnable, it automatically terminates

Comment: good example from docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Find some examples, read some documentation, learn something.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do this. But if your requirement is as simple as you say then a simple:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your task
    }
}).start();
```

would do.

Also, [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: Thanks mate, now as i need to call on this thread from different other locations in my code, can this thread be defined say at the bottom of my code and can i call then this code say runthread(); from where ever i want?

Answer (score 4):

What is a thread doing for you here?  I understand the obvious answer - "connect to a database and fetch/return some variables" - but it's not clear to me that this operation can be asynchronous for you.

I'd also recommend that you look into something more modern than a `Thread`.  There are new classes like `Executor` in the concurrency package that would be better than a raw `Thread`. Have a look at those if your problem truly can benefit.  If not, don't take on the complexity for its own sake.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to create a thread in java

1. Create a class that Extends the `Thread` class and ovrerride the run method
2. Create a class that implements `Runnable` and override the run method.

In run method, put your business logic to connect to database and do rest of the stuff.

Then in your code, you can create a thread and execute it by calling the `start` method on your thread calss. Learn more about creating and running threads here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). So that you will come to know how to run a thread.

and other reference in this [link](http://electrotek.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/thread-bound-db-connection-threadlocal/)

or take this as example :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ThreadConnection.init("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver", "jdbc:hsqldb:test", "sa", "");

        Connection connection = ThreadConnection.getConnection();
        // main thread's connection

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Connection connection = ThreadConnection.getConnection();
                    // this thread's connection
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, now as i need to call on this thread from different other locations in my code, can this thread be defined say at the bottom of my code and can i call then this code say runthread(); from where ever i want?